# How do I swap the instance names in Microsoft SQL server running different versions of SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have two instances of Microsoft SQL on my PC.  Original instance, default instance, is v2014, referenced as 12.0.42370.0 in the SMS screen shot image.  For an upgrade to our application, I installed a second instance of SQL, v2019 as MSSQLSERVER01.  It shows as 15.0.2000.5 in the SMS screen shot.

Our .net application uses the default instance, ie: . for the connection string.  For testing the new application, I changed the connection string to MSSQLSERVER01.  Now that our application has been released, I want to remove the older (default) version of SQL, and just keep V2019.

I also want to be able to reference the default connection as ".".  How can I swap these 2 instance names, so v2014 can be removed and be able to reference v2019 as the default instance name of .?
[image]

I reviewed the suggested tips for renaming an instance.  In this case, both instances are up and active though.

For the answer suggested below and my follow-up comments, I'm attached more screen shots:
[image]

[image]
In SMS the default connection . fails as expected as I've shut down the service and tcipip.

[image]
The second instance connection succeeds in SMS, still referenced by MSSQLSERVER01.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable the service for the old instance
2. Reconfigure the new instance to listen on port 1433 in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

That should redirect most apps using the hostname, '.', or `localhost` to the new instance.

Then connect to the instance in SSMS and look at the SQL Server Log you should see a message like `Server is listening on ['any' <ipv4> 1433]` and `Server name is <computerName>\<instanceName>`:

[image]

and running

`sqlcmd -S . -q "select @@servername"`

should output the named instance name.

Comment: Follow similar threads, that is why I did.  Stopped the MSSQLSERVER instance.  Even changed the IP protocol properties for IPall to another port. Then chnaged MSSQLSERVER01 instance IP protocol for IPall to 1433. Restarted that instance.  In SMS, both instances were still there after I rebooted PC.  Could not get to the default instance ., as the instance of MSSQLSERVER was stopped.  MSSQLSERVER01 still available.  I must be missing something.

Comment: Did you validate from the SQL Log that the instance is listening on 1433?

Comment: I did not, only because I didn't know I should do that.  Is there a management tool to view the log? I will look right away when I know how.

Comment: SQL Server 2017/2019 are perfectly happy in docker containers on a local machine, you can create as many instances as you want and map various port numbers to a hostname in hosts file. You can persist storage to local disk as well in case you need to keep the database files if container was rebuilt. Also sql server install is no longer needed on local machine.

Comment: For the default instance, ., named MSSQLSERVER, I disabled TCPIP and stopped the service.  Then I verified via the log for instance MSSQLSERVER01, log that it is listening on port 1443.  In SMS, attempts to connect to default instance, ., fail as expected.  Connecting to named instance MSSQLSERVER01 succeed.  So, I'm still not understanding how to swap the connection instance names (or get to the point that SQL v19 is reference by the default instance, .    The sqlcmd from command line fails: Could not open a connection to  SQL Server.

Comment: what about connecting to `tcp:localhost`?

Comment: I need to have the default instance referred to successfully as .    Our .net application is using a connection string of .  for connecting to the DB. That code is in our committed source and all devs on the team use .    I have to manually change the connection string to reference the MSSQLSERVER01 instance to get our app to work locally on my PC. Then I discard changes to that connection when my coding is done.  Kind of a pain and thus the reason I was attempting to swap instance names.  It just seems like it should be simple :)